# How to add tests into "integration" directory with ADD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress

I'm using containerized Cypress to run my tests. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/included:4.8.0

WORKDIR /

COPY ./cypress.json /cypress.json
ADD integration /cypress/integration

RUN npm install randomstring --silent
```

I know the Cypress image comes with cypress directory inside. So above I'm adding my tests using the keyword `ADD`. The problem is that it's not actually adding anything. The `integration` directory is in the same directory as the Dockerfile so it can't be that it can't be found.
I'm getting this error output:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

/cypress/integration
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `cypress.json` say the tests should be? Does this work *outside* the container? Note you're changing the relative position of the config file and the tests.

Comment: Yes the tests run fine outside the container.

Comment: cypress says it should be located in `cypress/integration`.